# Number & Decimal Validations using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to implement following validations.Please suggest any jQuery plugin for this.

### Case -1

Numeric
Number Range : (0-9999)
Non Negative
Non Decimal

### Case -2

Numeric
Number Range : (0-99.99)
Non Negative
Decimal with more than 2 digits after decimal is not allowed

### Case -3

Numeric
Number Range : (0-99999)
Non Negative
Decimal @ first position or last position

Answer (score 0):

better use server side validations, javascript validations are client-side and can be hacked easily

Edit: using the jQuery validation plugin

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      range: [0,9999]
    }
  }
});
```

The second case is a bit strange, are you passing strings to the database? try with

```
number: true
max: 99.99
min: 0
```

Comment: yes you can, and it may reduce server consumption by pre-validating, but client-side only is a very bad practice

Comment: obviously i will use server side validations but i want to refine the data from client side as much as possible

Comment: i completly agree with you , we have done server side also in my project, which is really safe

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery validation plugin

http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js
http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js
http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.pack.js
http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/additional-methods.js

The demos are available at
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation